# How to iterate over files in specific directories?

Tags: python, pathlib

I'd like to iterate over files in two folders in a directory only, and ignore any other files/directories.
e.g in path: "dirA/subdirA/folder1" and "dirA/subdirA/folder2"

I tried passing both to pathlib as:

```
root_dir_A = "dirA/subdirA/folder1"
root_dir_B = "dirA/subdirA/folder2"
for file in Path(root_dir_A,root_dir_B).glob('**/*.json'):
    json_data = open(file, encoding="utf8")
    ...
```

But it only iterates over the 2nd path in `Path(root_dir_A,root_dir_B)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass two separate directories to `Path()`. You'll need to loop over them.

```
for dirpath in (root_dir_A, root_dir_B):
    for file in Path(dirpath).glob('**/*.json'):
         ...
```

According to the documentation, `Path("foo", "bar")` should produce `"foo/bar"`; but it seems to actually use only the second path segment if it is absolute. Either way, it doesn't do what you seemed to hope it would.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the output of `Path(root_dir_A,root_dir_B)` to see if it returns what you want.

In your specific case this should work:

```
path_root = Path('dirA')

for path in path_root.glob('subdirA/folder[12]/*/*.json'):
    ...
```

If your paths aren't homogeneous enough you might have to chain generators. I. e.:

```
from itertools import chain

content_dir_A = Path(root_dir_A).glob('**/*.json')
content_dir_B = Path(root_dir_B).glob('**/*.json')

content_all = chain(content_dir_A, content_dir_B)

for path in content_all:
    ...
```